# Using Zucchini juice in bread recipe

Tags: bread, juice, zucchini

I was freezing some shredded zucchini yesterday and squeezed out the juice. Made me wonder whether you can substitute zucchini juice or other juice for water when making sandwich bread in bread machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can.  The difficultly would be that any vegetable or fruit juice will be at least slightly acidic, as well as having a small amount of multiple nutrients in it.  The juice's actual effect on the bread would be unpredictable, and you'd just have to try it and see how it goes.

In most cases, I would expect that the juice has no real effect on the resulting bread.  But you might discover a great new recipe.

Comment: It’s probably more challenging in a bread maker (which the asker plans to use) with pre-programmed timings. Judging times via visual and haptic clues may be better in this case. Nevertheless, I‘m also in favor of just giving it a go and see what happens.

Comment: Yah.  Our breadmaker is pretty tolerant of messing about, but I realize that not all are.

Comment: [Zucchini is alkaline until cooked.](https://www.healabel.com/zucchini-benefits/)

Comment: @Abion47 huh!  Do you know any more trustworthy source for that information?  The linked article isn't, and I can't find any scientific authority that gives pH for raw zucchini.

Comment: @FuzzyChef I was thinking the same thing, but every other source I can find seems to be pulling up pH for only cooked zucchini which strikes me as odd. I might need to go to the store and get a zucchini to test myself.

Comment: Well, raw zucchini is not frequently eaten.

Comment: It's not something that I personally like, but I thought that raw zucchini was a somewhat popular addition to salads, particularly in Mediterranean cuisines.

Comment: It's a thing.  It's just not that common.  And most of these food stats come from the US FDA or USDA, and a lot of those are based on how Americans ate foods in the 1970s.  So they didn't cover raw zucchini because they didn't think of it as a food.  The FDA nutrition lists are full of weird ommissions like this.

Comment: FWIW, shredded raw zucchini with pecorino cheese and black pepper is delish.  But I don't know if it's alkaline or not ;-)